# Trying detect image Values using Google Cloud Vision using c# asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-vision

Trying detect image Values using Google Cloud Vision using c# asp.net c# but i am getting below error.

```
Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations: C:\Users\mazharkhan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\googleapi\bin\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,C:\Users\mazharkhan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\googleapi\bin\runtimes/win/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,C:\Users\mazharkhan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\googleapi\bin\../..\runtimes/win/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll
```

I am getting error in below line. And tried to open this url is not working: http://vision.googleapis.com

```
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(@"http://vision.googleapis.com", credential.ToChannelCredentials()); // <-- Getting error in this line
```

Below is my design code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

Below is my code which worte in button click for display in label

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(@"C:\!\cat.jpg");
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"C:\!\Tutorials-0a2efaf1b53c.json");
    var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(@"http://vision.googleapis.com", credential.ToChannelCredentials()); // <-- Getting error in this line 
    var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
    var response = client.DetectText(image); 
    foreach (var annotation in response)
    {
        if (annotation.Description != null)
            //    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            Label1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";

    }

}
```

I used below example url:

[Detecting content in Google Cloud Vision for .NET does nothing/hangs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999636/detecting-content-in-google-cloud-vision-for-net-does-nothing-hangs-app)

I created service key account also in google for json file.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error isn't really about the Vision API, or authentication - it's due to gRPC not loading properly. It sounds like you're using a "Web Site" project rather than a "Web Application" project. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12570) - there's a workaround of copying the relevant library into the `bin` directory at execution time before starting to use gRPC, but I'd advise against that.

I'd advise using a Web Application project instead, if you possibly can.

Comment: Then why this url is not opening: http://vision.googleapis.com. @Jon Skeet

Comment: I created web application project now application is hangs in this line : var response = client.DetectText(image); // <-- Nothing happens, app hangs, why?. @Jon Skeet

Comment: @mazhar124: No, this is not a chat site. Please don't expect real-time support. `vision.googleapis.com` is not a web site to open in a browser - it's an API endpoint. For the next problem, please ask a new question with sample code and more context. I'd also suggest trying the API in a console application to start with - that's a simpler context to use to diagnose problems.

Comment: @zyonneo: We don't support Unity for the GCP libraries I work on, I'm afraid. They *may* work with recent versions of gRPC, but they're not supported and you'd need to work out all the details of bundling the gRPC libraries - as well as auth.

Comment: @JonSkeet Without plugin for the app, I was looking for something like this -https://codeshare.io/5ZBv9X .Any tutorial to write basic code to connect APIs without plugins.Planning to take a photo containing text with device(IOS/Android) camera ,copy image path and send the image to Google Vision Api for detecting text in the image.Later retrieve the text in the app.Will the image gets stored in the google server(Dont want that).

Comment: @zyonneo: I don't know which plugin you're talking about, I'm afraid. Or do you mean the library? Could you explain why you don't want to use any libraries? That will make things much, much harder for you. As far as I'm *aware*, the image isn't stored by Google, but I could be wrong. It feels like this is a somewhat separate issue to the one in the question, as you're not trying to use gRPC. I'd suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570986/how-to-read-text-from-a-surface-in-real-time-from-device-camera-using-unity