# LINQPad missing dll for Grpc

Tags: c#, ocr, linqpad

I am trying to test some methods in my library using Google API.  More specifically the Cloud Vision API.  When I reference the library in LINQPad I get an error

> FileNotFoundException: Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5_dgzgzeqb\shadow_fxuunf\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5_dgzgzeqb\shadow_fxuunf\runtimes/win/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5_dgzgzeqb\shadow_fxuunf../..\runtimes/win/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll

I have tried copying the dll into all of these locations as well as my LINQPad Plugins and the LINQPad folder.  I have tried clearing Cancel and Clear query thinking I needed to reset it.  I  have also closed and reopened LINQPad thinking maybe it re-scans the directory on load.  None of this has worked.  Has LINQPad changed where to put dlls or am I missing something?

I am using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1

`

```
var file = new byte[128];
var _settingsCon = new SettingConnector();
var apiKey = Task.Run(() => _settingsCon.Get("Google:Key")).Result.Value;
var credential = Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromJson(apiKey);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(
    ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(),
    credential.ToChannelCredentials());
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var image = Image.FromBytes(file);
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
foreach (var page in response.Pages)
{
    foreach (var block in page.Blocks)
    {
        foreach (var paragraph in block.Paragraphs)
        {
            builder.Append(paragraph);
        }
    }
}
builder.ToString().Dump();`
```

This is essentially the function.  The file is a dummy file that would be passed in.  It shouldn't matter cause it can't make the request any way.  The Dump is used instead of return.

Comment: Try using the [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer).

Comment: Are you referencing the NuGet package? If so, what's the package ID, and can you post a sample query that generates the error?

Comment: its probably related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715542/trying-detect-image-values-using-google-cloud-vision-using-c-sharp-asp-net-c-sha/50715652 , have you manged to solve it in LINQPad?